# How to use has or have when referring to "These groups"

Tags: grammaticality

Must I use "has order  44215589120 with index 1120" or "have orders 44215589120 with indices 1120" when referring to "These groups" in the sentence **"These groups are all isomorphic to each other and has order 4421589120 with index  1120 in O(8,3)."**
With "isomorphic to each other" it is meant that the groups are essentially the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the subject is '**these** groups', the verb should be plural.

Comment: The simplicity of the English should not be hidden by the complexity of the mathematics. I understand that groups that are isomorphic each have the same order. If not, they would not be isomorphic. Hence *each group has the order 44…* or *these groups have the order 44…* I agree with @KateBunting

Comment: There is an inherent infelicity in your suggested versions. "These groups are all isomorphic to each other, the common identifiers being order 4421589120 with index 1120 in O(8,3)."

Comment: You can also omit the verb entirely: *These groups are all isomorphic to each other, with order 4421589120 with index 1120 in O(8,3).*